# Other virtual drive formats for linking to physical disk device or to archive content

Tags: partition, symbolic-link, image, mappeddrive, metadata

It is known that you can link to physical disk device through VMDK virtual drive format. It works on Mac*, Lin*, Win* with VirtualBox or VMware ( [here solution with VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk is described](https://superuser.com/questions/495025/use-physical-harddisk-in-virtual-box) ).

I repeat: it is about symbolic linking to physical device, archive content, block device or FS partition in OS, but not about [creating image copy of physical device data](https://askubuntu.com/questions/853160/create-image-with-dd-command-cow2).

So, what are other virtual drive formats (except vmdk), which supports symbolic (logical) linking to physical disk device (in Linux or Windows operating systems)?

P.S.: Read only mode is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Several hypervisors allow direct attach of disks. KVM raw, Hyper-V pass through.

Neither uses a disk file containing raw disk metadata instead of data. That seems to be a peculiarity of VMDK.

Comment: Please edit your question if those are requirements of yours.

Comment: Partial answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22327728/mounting-vmdk-disk-image/49000377#49000377